# How can I post to my Instagram page through ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I have succeeded in posting to my facebook page through rails by 'fb-graph' gem.
And I want to post to my instagram page through rails now. How can I post to my Instagram page through ruby on rails? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible ruby provide Instagram client (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/Instagram/Client)

Comment: I've already seen it, but there are only way to get the post from instagram page.

Comment: I am googling Instagram provide post photo into Instagram please refer this link [link] (https://www.devwalks.com/lets-build-instagram-in-rails-part-1/) and Instagram provide some API to use GET or POST to Instagram Refer this to  [link] (https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/)